# iOS Swift verify receipt JSON fetch issue

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

While testing my in-app subscription, I find out that the `latest_receipt` is possible to get. When it comes to running the app at the release mode on App Store, all new app users find the exception at the line of code :

```
  let latestReceipt = responseTransaction.object(forKey: "latest_receipt") as! String
```

Would you please tell me under IAP documentation, what is the possible state of this the field `latest_receipt`? and it turns empty or null responses?

When I use sandbox, it often gives :

```
{
    "latest_receipt": "MIIbngYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIbj...",
    "status": 0,
    "receipt": {
        "download_id": 0,
        "receipt_creation_date_ms": "1486371475000",
        "application_version": "2",
        "app_item_id": 0,
        "receipt_creation_date": "2017-02-06 08:57:55 Etc/GMT",
        "original_purchase_date": "2013-08-01 07:00:00 Etc/GMT",
        "request_date_pst": "2017-02-06 04:41:09 America/Los_Angeles",
        "original_application_version": "1.0",
        "original_purchase_date_pst": "2013-08-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
        "request_date_ms": "1486384869996",
        "bundle_id": "com.yourcompany.yourapp",
        "request_date": "2017-02-06 12:41:09 Etc/GMT",
        "original_purchase_date_ms": "1375340400000",
        "in_app": [{
            "purchase_date_ms": "1486371474000",
            "web_order_line_item_id": "1000000034281189",
            "original_purchase_date_ms": "1486371475000",
            "original_purchase_date": "2017-02-06 08:57:55 Etc/GMT",
            "expires_date_pst": "2017-02-06 01:00:54 America/Los_Angeles",
            "original_purchase_date_pst": "2017-02-06 00:57:55 America/Los_Angeles",
            "purchase_date_pst": "2017-02-06 00:57:54 America/Los_Angeles",
            "expires_date_ms": "1486371654000",
            "expires_date": "2017-02-06 09:00:54 Etc/GMT",
            "original_transaction_id": "1000000271014363",
            "purchase_date": "2017-02-06 08:57:54 Etc/GMT",
            "quantity": "1",
            "is_trial_period": "false",
            "product_id": "com.yourcompany.yourapp",
            "transaction_id": "1000000271014363"
        }],
        "version_external_identifier": 0,
        "receipt_creation_date_pst": "2017-02-06 00:57:55 America/Los_Angeles",
        "adam_id": 0,
        "receipt_type": "ProductionSandbox"
    },
```

When pushing into production, it gives something like :

```
 {'environment': 'Production',
  'receipt': {'adam_id': 1465637208,
              'app_item_id': 1465637208,
              'application_version': '33',
              'bundle_id': 'gogoyuedu.testing.anc',
              'download_id': 7505071111117518,
              'in_app': [],
              'original_application_version': '31',
              'original_purchase_date': '2019-09-30 05:16:04 Etc/GMT',
              'original_purchase_date_ms': '1569820564000',
              'original_purchase_date_pst': '2019-09-29 22:16:04 '
                                            'America/Los_Angeles',
              'receipt_creation_date': '2019-10-02 08:49:40 Etc/GMT',
              'receipt_creation_date_ms': '1570006180000',
              'receipt_creation_date_pst': '2019-10-02 01:49:40 '
                                           'America/Los_Angeles',
              'receipt_type': 'Production',
              'request_date': '2019-10-02 08:49:47 Etc/GMT',
              'request_date_ms': '1570006187285',
              'request_date_pst': '2019-10-02 01:49:47 America/Los_Angeles',
             'version_external_identifier': 832979108},
  'status': 0}
```

At my swift method, should I get purchases record under attribute `in_app` instead of `latest_receipt_info` ?

If so, how can I get my latest receipt at the field `in_app`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always a good idea to be on the safe side:

try

```
if let latestReceipt = responseTransaction.object(forKey: "latest_receipt") as? String {
// do something here
}
```

It might be the reason that the "new" users have no latest receipts but you have on your phone because you already "bought" something?!

Comment: Probably and Please see my new edit. I find something interesting

Comment: Chris, would you please tell me that you if let statement can avoid exception if the json response rendered by `latest_receipt ` is missing ?

Comment: @RajuyourPepe: if the if-statement works, the latestRecipe variable will filled with a non optional value, if the if-statement does not work (no value in latest_receipt), you can show an error in the else statement. If you force the variabel to be a String like you did ( as! String) and it is a nil value which you are forcing - it will crash.